# Firestore: "Missing or insufficient permissions" Can you define or retrieve more details on error?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

`FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Is there any way to setup the rules so that we can retrieve a more specific error? Such as whether or not they can't read, or write, due to X or Y reason?

Just curious, thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to find the root cause of the violation.  This would be a security problem for your app (it gives attackers a hint on what your protections are like - they should be private).  And, for very complicated rules, it would be difficult to express exactly what part of the rule was violated.

If you absolutely need to know, route all your changes through a HTTPS [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) that programmatically checks all the constraints and communicates that back to the caller.

Comment: It sure would be nice if there was debugging (or logging) for security rules.  The other way is the old binary search.  Remove 1/2 your rules until you find the rule that isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: @doug stevenson, can you extrapolate on why the secrecy of the rules is important for security? i would have assumed that the fact that adversaries can't change them is the important part. in what circumstances does the adversary benefit if they simply know them?

Comment: @okhobb Imagine someone is trying to hack your account by guessing its password.  Would you prefer that hacker know some reason why their guess was incorrect (say, too short, or not enough character variance)?  Or would you prefer to reveal nothing at all about their failed guess?

Comment: when authenticating a user by password there's no reason do any checks other than to check if the salted+hashed user input equals what the backend knows. moreover, interacting with firestore documents seems like an unusual choice for doing authentication. better just to use the firebase.auth package.

Comment: @okhobb That example was metaphorical.  I hope my main point was clear that you want an attacker to know **nothing** about **any** rules, so that they have the most difficult time trying to circumvent them.

Comment: to clarify the point of my comment, if your app's rules allow **any** circumvention possibility then you have a security problem. if the attacker knows the rules they may exploit it more quickly, but that's not solving your security problem. i'd argue that firebase users should design their rules/schema with this in mind: it's not relevant if the rules are secret. would you dissuade an open-source project from using firestore and adding the rules to their repo?

Comment: @okhobb You're talking about two different things. The OP asked if it was possible to know (at runtime, in prod) which rule was violated. My opinion is that you don't want anyone to know these things in prod because it effectively makes it easier to discover possible breakin vectors. Publishing rules in an open source project is a different issue, and it's up to the repo maintainer to determine if and why that's worthwhile. What's in the repo might be irrelevant, because it may not match what's been deployed somewhere. The owner of an active deployment is ultimately responsible for their data.

Comment: @okhobb If the owner of said deployment trusts the rules, then so be it. If they don't, they have an obligation to fix them, or simply refuse to deploy the project.  An open source project may also have only one deployment (the owner-developer), in which case, they are not obliged to publish any rules at all. They decide. The public can remain out of the loop.

Comment: i agree with OP it would be a nice feature to enable verbose error messages. it could be off by default. you use it in your dev environment and not prod if you think you have possible security problems in your rules that you want to obfuscate.

Comment: @okhobb You're more than welcome to file a feature request for that. More than likely, I suspect, Firestore will instead eventually have an in-console rules tester similar to Realtime Database.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/